# How to connect to ftp server trough VPN

Tags: vpn, ftp

There is a remote FTP server, which has my VPN Gateway IP address in white list. I have a name of FTP server, username and password. How can I connect to it? (I need my connection to go through VPN)

Comment: SFTP is very different from FTP (basically, SFTP works over SSH). Since your question asks about FTP, I removed the SFTP tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# route add <name-or-ip-of-ftp-server> gw <gateway-ip>
$ ftp <name-or-ip-of-ftp-server> [<port>]
```

then type your username and password

Answer (score -2):

Superior permissions are required... Use your client server data file that contains client server address. set your permissions for access. Secure your ssl certificate. Retrieve server address through client list access. Load server data files with clients list through ftp share\server name. Protocols for server access may be required.  After completing test for server access, trace source of data files to retrieve additional server addresses. Check file names for your own personal ftp vpn access. Set access to private or share. If possible, use monitor files to list all access address for later installations.